# How to get aggregates of tags you've answered for

Tags: support

I've been answering (or attempting to answer) many different questions.

I've now answered a fair a bit.

I would like to now subscribe (Via rss) to the tags that I answer the most questions for so that I can find them faster; however, I'm not quite sure how to find out the tags  I answered the most. There is certainly a way to find out what tags  you ask the most questions for; however, is there a way to find the tags you answer questions for the most?

I suspect must be a way to do this as there are badges for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Tags section of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2656813/aelphaeis?tab=tags) will indicate which tags you have been most active in.  You've been most active in the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag.

Comment: I knew it was something easy. Now I feel silly. Thanks for the help.